# ROI extraction from Opencv Videoframe

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, roi

How to extract ROI from an OpenCV Video frame?

I have developed a code for tracking and counting system. I need help in implementing some more logic in my code.

**Help Required Section:** Extract the images of the object when it crosses the Reference line.
I want to extract the images of the object having rectangular box ROI.

**Below is my code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pandas as pd

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('traffic.mp4')
frames_count, fps, width, height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS), cap.get(
    cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
width = int(width)
height = int(height)

# creates a pandas data frame with the number of rows the same length as frame count
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(int(frames_count)))
df.index.name = "Frames"

framenumber = 0  # keeps track of current frame
Chocolatecrossedup = 0  # keeps track of Chocolates that crossed up
Chocolatecrosseddown = 0  # keeps track of Chocolates that crossed down
Chocolateids = []  # blank list to add Chocolate ids
Chocolateidscrossed = []  # blank list to add Chocolate ids that have crossed
totalChocolates = 0  # keeps track of total Chocolates

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()  # create background subtractor

# information to start saving a video file
ret, frame = cap.read()  # import image
ratio = .5  # resize ratio
image = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), None, ratio, ratio)  # resize image
width2, height2, channels = image.shape
video = cv2.VideoWriter('Chocolate_counter.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), fps, (height2, width2), 1)

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()  # import image

    if ret:  # if there is a frame continue with code

        image = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), None, ratio, ratio)  # resize image

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # converts image to gray

        fgmask = fgbg.apply(gray)  # uses the background subtraction

        # applies different thresholds to fgmask to try and isolate Chocolates
        # just have to keep playing around with settings until Chocolates are easily identifiable
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))  # kernel to apply to the morphology
        closing = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
        opening = cv2.morphologyEx(closing, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
        dilation = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel)
        retvalbin, bins = cv2.threshold(dilation, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # removes the shadows

        # creates contours
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bins, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        # use convex hull to create polygon around contours
        hull = [cv2.convexHull(c) for c in contours]

        # draw contours
        #cv2.drawContours(image, hull, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

        # line created to stop counting contours, needed as Chocolates in distance become one big contour
        lineypos = 225
        cv2.line(image, (0, lineypos), (width, lineypos), (255, 0, 0), 5)

        # line y position created to count contours
        lineypos2 = 250
        cv2.line(image, (0, lineypos2), (width, lineypos2), (0, 255, 0), 5)

        # min area for contours in case a bunch of small noise contours are created
        minarea = 300

        # max area for contours, can be quite large for buses
        maxarea = 50000

        # vectors for the x and y locations of contour centroids in current frame
        cxx = np.zeros(len(contours))
        cyy = np.zeros(len(contours))

        for i in range(len(contours)):  # cycles through all contours in current frame

            if hierarchy[0, i, 3] == -1:  # using hierarchy to only count parent contours (contours not within others)

                area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])  # area of contour

                if minarea < area < maxarea:  # area threshold for contour

                    # calculating centroids of contours
                    cnt = contours[i]
                    M = cv2.moments(cnt)
                    cx = int(M['m10'] / M['m00'])
                    cy = int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])

                    if cy > lineypos:  # filters out contours that are above line (y starts at top)

                        # gets bounding points of contour to create rectangle
                        # x,y is top left corner and w,h is width and height
                        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

                        # creates a rectangle around contour
                        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

                        # Prints centroid text in order to double check later on
                        cv2.putText(image, str(cx) + "," + str(cy), (cx + 10, cy + 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                                    .3, (0, 0, 255), 1)

                        cv2.drawMarker(image, (cx, cy), (0, 0, 255), cv2.MARKER_STAR, markerSize=5, thickness=1,
                                       line_type=cv2.LINE_AA)

                        # adds centroids that passed previous criteria to centroid list
                        cxx[i] = cx
                        cyy[i] = cy

        # eliminates zero entries (centroids that were not added)
        cxx = cxx[cxx != 0]
        cyy = cyy[cyy != 0]

        # empty list to later check which centroid indices were added to dataframe
        minx_index2 = []
        miny_index2 = []

        # maximum allowable radius for current frame centroid to be considered the same centroid from previous frame
        maxrad = 25

        # The section below keeps track of the centroids and assigns them to old Chocolateids or new Chocolateids

        if len(cxx):  # if there are centroids in the specified area

            if not Chocolateids:  # if Chocolateids is empty

                for i in range(len(cxx)):  # loops through all centroids

                    Chocolateids.append(i)  # adds a Chocolate id to the empty list Chocolateids
                    df[str(Chocolateids[i])] = ""  # adds a column to the dataframe corresponding to a Chocolateid

                    # assigns the centroid values to the current frame (row) and Chocolateid (column)
                    df.at[int(framenumber), str(Chocolateids[i])] = [cxx[i], cyy[i]]

                    totalChocolates = Chocolateids[i] + 1  # adds one count to total Chocolates

            else:  # if there are already Chocolate ids

                dx = np.zeros((len(cxx), len(Chocolateids)))  # new arrays to calculate deltas
                dy = np.zeros((len(cyy), len(Chocolateids)))  # new arrays to calculate deltas

                for i in range(len(cxx)):  # loops through all centroids

                    for j in range(len(Chocolateids)):  # loops through all recorded Chocolate ids

                        # acquires centroid from previous frame for specific Chocolateid
                        oldcxcy = df.iloc[int(framenumber - 1)][str(Chocolateids[j])]

                        # acquires current frame centroid that doesn't necessarily line up with previous frame centroid
                        curcxcy = np.array([cxx[i], cyy[i]])

                        if not oldcxcy:  # checks if old centroid is empty in case Chocolate leaves screen and new Chocolate shows

                            continue  # continue to next Chocolateid

                        else:  # calculate centroid deltas to compare to current frame position later

                            dx[i, j] = oldcxcy[0] - curcxcy[0]
                            dy[i, j] = oldcxcy[1] - curcxcy[1]

                for j in range(len(Chocolateids)):  # loops through all current Chocolate ids

                    sumsum = np.abs(dx[:, j]) + np.abs(dy[:, j])  # sums the deltas wrt to Chocolate ids

                    # finds which index carid had the min difference and this is true index
                    correctindextrue = np.argmin(np.abs(sumsum))
                    minx_index = correctindextrue
                    miny_index = correctindextrue

                    # acquires delta values of the minimum deltas in order to check if it is within radius later on
                    mindx = dx[minx_index, j]
                    mindy = dy[miny_index, j]

                    if mindx == 0 and mindy == 0 and np.all(dx[:, j] == 0) and np.all(dy[:, j] == 0):
                        # checks if minimum value is 0 and checks if all deltas are zero since this is empty set
                        # delta could be zero if centroid didn't move

                        continue  # continue to next Chocolateid

                    else:

                        # if delta values are less than maximum radius then add that centroid to that specific Chocolateid
                        if np.abs(mindx) < maxrad and np.abs(mindy) < maxrad:

                            # adds centroid to corresponding previously existing Chocolateid
                            df.at[int(framenumber), str(Chocolateids[j])] = [cxx[minx_index], cyy[miny_index]]
                            minx_index2.append(minx_index)  # appends all the indices that were added to previous Chocolateids
                            miny_index2.append(miny_index)

                for i in range(len(cxx)):  # loops through all centroids

                    # if centroid is not in the minindex list then another Chocolate needs to be added
                    if i not in minx_index2 and miny_index2:

                        df[str(totalChocolates)] = ""  # create another column with total Chocolates
                        totalChocolates = totalChocolates + 1  # adds another total Chocolate the count
                        t = totalChocolates - 1  # t is a placeholder to total Chocolates
                        Chocolateids.append(t)  # append to list of Chocolate ids
                        df.at[int(framenumber), str(t)] = [cxx[i], cyy[i]]  # add centroid to the new Chocolate id

                    elif curcxcy[0] and not oldcxcy and not minx_index2 and not miny_index2:
                        # checks if current centroid exists but previous centroid does not
                        # new Chocolate to be added in case minx_index2 is empty

                        df[str(totalChocolates)] = ""  # create another column with total Chocolates
                        totalChocolates = totalChocolates + 1  # adds another total Chocolate the count
                        t = totalChocolates - 1  # t is a placeholder to total Chocolates
                        Chocolateids.append(t)  # append to list of Chocolate ids
                        df.at[int(framenumber), str(t)] = [cxx[i], cyy[i]]  # add centroid to the new Chocolate id

        # The section below labels the centroids on screen

        currentChocolates = 0  # current Chocolates on screen
        currentChocolatesindex = []  # current Chocolates on screen Chocolateid index

        for i in range(len(Chocolateids)):  # loops through all Chocolateids

            if df.at[int(framenumber), str(Chocolateids[i])] != '':
                # checks the current frame to see which Chocolate ids are active
                # by checking in centroid exists on current frame for certain Chocolate id

                currentChocolates = currentChocolates + 1  # adds another to current Chocolates on screen
                currentChocolatesindex.append(i)  # adds Chocolate ids to current Chocolates on screen

        for i in range(currentChocolates):  # loops through all current Chocolate ids on screen

            # grabs centroid of certain Chocolateid for current frame
            curcent = df.iloc[int(framenumber)][str(Chocolateids[currentChocolatesindex[i]])]

            # grabs centroid of certain Chocolateid for previous frame
            oldcent = df.iloc[int(framenumber - 1)][str(Chocolateids[currentChocolatesindex[i]])]

            if curcent:  # if there is a current centroid

                # On-screen text for current centroid
                cv2.putText(image, "Centroid" + str(curcent[0]) + "," + str(curcent[1]),
                            (int(curcent[0]), int(curcent[1])), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .5, (0, 255, 255), 2)

                cv2.putText(image, "ID:" + str(Chocolateids[currentChocolatesindex[i]]), (int(curcent[0]), int(curcent[1] - 15)),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .5, (0, 255, 255), 2)

                cv2.drawMarker(image, (int(curcent[0]), int(curcent[1])), (0, 0, 255), cv2.MARKER_STAR, markerSize=5,
                               thickness=1, line_type=cv2.LINE_AA)

                if oldcent:  # checks if old centroid exists
                    # adds radius box from previous centroid to current centroid for visualization
                    xstart = oldcent[0] - maxrad
                    ystart = oldcent[1] - maxrad
                    xwidth = oldcent[0] + maxrad
                    yheight = oldcent[1] + maxrad
                    cv2.rectangle(image, (int(xstart), int(ystart)), (int(xwidth), int(yheight)), (0, 125, 0), 1)

                    # checks if old centroid is on or below line and curcent is on or above line
                    # to count Chocolates and that Chocolate hasn't been counted yet
                    if oldcent[1] >= lineypos2 and curcent[1] <= lineypos2 and Chocolateids[
                        currentChocolatesindex[i]] not in Chocolateidscrossed:

                        Chocolatecrossedup = Chocolatecrossedup + 1
                        cv2.line(image, (0, lineypos2), (width, lineypos2), (0, 0, 255), 5)
                        Chocolateidscrossed.append(
                            currentChocolatesindex[i])  # adds Chocolate id to list of count Chocolate to prevent double counting

                    # checks if old centroid is on or above line and curcent is on or below line
                    # to count Chocolates and that Chocolate hasn't been counted yet
                    elif oldcent[1] <= lineypos2 and curcent[1] >= lineypos2 and Chocolateids[
                        currentChocolatesindex[i]] not in Chocolateidscrossed:

                        Chocolatecrosseddown = Chocolatecrosseddown + 1
                        cv2.line(image, (0, lineypos2), (width, lineypos2), (0, 0, 125), 5)
                        Chocolateidscrossed.append(currentChocolatesindex[i])

        # Top left hand corner on-screen text
        cv2.rectangle(image, (0, 0), (250, 100), (255, 0, 0), -1)  # background rectangle for on-screen text

        cv2.putText(image, "Chocolates in Area: " + str(currentChocolates), (0, 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .5, (0, 170, 0), 1)

        cv2.putText(image, "Chocolates Crossed Down: " + str(Chocolatecrosseddown), (0, 45), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .5,(0, 170, 0), 1)

        cv2.putText(image, "Total Chocolates Detected: " + str(len(Chocolateids)), (0, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .5, (0, 170, 0), 1)

        cv2.putText(image, 'Time: ' + str(round(framenumber / fps, 2)) + ' sec of ' + str(round(frames_count / fps, 2)) + ' sec', (0, 90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .5, (0, 170, 0), 1)

        # displays images and transformations
        cv2.imshow("countours", image)
        cv2.moveWindow("countours", 0, 0)

        video.write(image)  # save the current image to video file from earlier

        # adds to framecount
        framenumber = framenumber + 1

        k = cv2.waitKey(int(1000/fps)) & 0xff  # int(1000/fps) is normal speed since waitkey is in ms
        if k == 27:
            break

    else:  
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**GUI:**
[image]

**Expecting Result**

When the car passes the green line. The image of the car automatically gets saved in a directory/folder. I only need the images of the ROI extracted from the videoframe.

Comment: Assuming you can obtain the rectanglular box ROI from `x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)` you can extract a ROI with `ROI = image[y:y+h, x+x+w]`. You can save it by keeping a counter `count = 0` and save with `cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(count), ROI)` and `count += 1` after. Put this into the section where you used to do `cv2.drawContours`

Comment: I have used `cv2.drawContours` below `contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bins, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`
and then I have used convex hull to create a polygon around contours
`hull = [cv2.convexHull(c) for c in contours]` and then I have drawn contours
 `cv2.drawContours(image, hull, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)` but later on after modifying the code I inactive the contours, can you help me with your suggestion by suggesting it in code.

Comment: I want to extract the images of objects when it crosses the green line showing the Centroid of the object. and If you can also suggest storing it's the position too, then it will be a great help for me.